# Excel If Else formula in VBA does not seem to identify string values

Tags: vba, excel

My Sheet Looks like this-

Sheet3

### A    |    B

s1   |  FALSE

s2   |    0

s3   |    0

s4   |    0

s5   |    0

s6   |  FALSE

s7   |    0

s8   |    0

s9   |    0

---

My Macro code is-

```
Sub CopyValue()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 490
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2) = "FALSE" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I am trying to copy the values of column B to column C wherever there is "FALSE". I have tried running this code. It runs but it does not show any results. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check against the value `false` without the quotes. Now you are comparing a string to a boolean (`true/false` value), which might lead to an undesired result.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. Actually the FALSE cells are characters and 0 ones are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try an UCase in front of comparison to convert it into Text, otherwise I believe Excel is taking them as Boolean values.

```
If UCase(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2)) = "FALSE" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2).Value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyValue()

Dim i As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    For i = 1 To 490
        If UCase(.Range("B" & i).Value) = "FALSE" Then
            .Range("C" & i).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you may consider two approaches

---

**AutoFilter approach**

where you need to have first row with headers

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("Sheet3") '<--| reference your sheet
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "B" cells from row 1 (headers) down to last not empty one
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="FALSE" '<--| filter referenced cells with "FALSE" string
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(, 1).Value = "'FALSE" '<--| if any filtered cell then write "'FALSE" in their adjacent cells, skipping header
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Formula & `SpecialCells()` Approach**

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("Sheet3") '<--| reference your sheet
        On Error Resume Next '<--| ignore errors should they arise from no text cells being found by subsequent 'SpecialCells()' method
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Offset(, 1) '<--| reference its column "B" cells from row 1 down to last not empty one range shifet by one column to the right
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=""FALSE"",""'FALSE"","""")" '<--| write the formula
            .Value = .Value '<--| substitute the formula with the value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```